# Topological space of continuous function is not compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm struggling with this question:

> Let $C[0,1]$ be set of continuous function of $[0,1]$. Define metric $d(f,g)=\int^1_0|f(x)-g(x)|dx$. Show that $C[0,1]$, with topology $\tau$ induced by $d$, is not a compact space.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Do you mean compact or complete?

Comment: I mean compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a (normed) vector space ($d$ result for a norm) , hence not bounded, so not compact.

Comment: How about proving from the definition? (Open cover doesn't has finite subcover)

Comment: Use the cover $\{B(f,1)\}_{f\in C[0,1] }$, there is no finite sub-cover. Where $B(f,1)$ is the open ball of center $f$ and radius $1$.

Comment: In general, every (non-zero) normed vector space $(E,\|.\|)$ is not compact.

Comment: @Hamou Is it ture? How can we prove that?